# Using JPA CompositeKey uses a property from another Entity

Tags: jpa

I tried searching but was having problems finding what I want. I have the following schema( * indicates primary key)

```
USER
  *UserId
  -Desc
Registration
  *DeviceId
  *UserId
  -date
```

So I want to create a primary key for Registration like...

```
@Embeddable
public class RegPk{
    private String deviceId;
    private User user;
    @Column(name="DEV_ID")
    public String getDevId(){
      return deviceId;
    }
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID")
    public User getUser() {
      return user;
    }
    ...
}
```

Is this right? Will it update the USER_ID field properly update in registration when I persist?

When I try this kind of thing out I get the following....

> [10/7/13 13:37:07:156 EDT] 000000ae webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Hello]:  org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException: The id class specified by type "class org.me.mfa.jpa.Registration" does not match the primary key fields of the class.  Make sure your identity class has the same primary keys as your persistent type, including pk field types. Mismatched property: "user"

So what now?

Comment: Show the Registration entity, as it looks like you are trying to use RegPk as an embeddedId class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA does not allow primary key classes to contain relationships, only basic types.  JPA 2.0 allows relationships to be apart of the ID, but you would move the relationship to the entity class, and have RegPk contain a deviceId and UserId.  The Device-User relationship would then be marked with either @Id or @MapsId("user") depending on if you wanted to use a @PKClass or @EmbeddedId within your entity.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/DerivedIdentifiers for an example using a pk class.

In JPA 1.0, you would use a similar setup, except that your Device-User relationship would be marked read-only (either by specifying the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation, or by marking the @JoinColumn with insertable=false, updatable=false).  You would then need to set the primary key basic mapping value manually, pulling the value from the referenced User entity directly.  This of course requires that the id in User already be assigned, which might require additional work if both objects are new.

Comment: I am using 2.0 and that is pretty much exactly what I came up with. Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I would add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to `@ManyToOne` annotation to forward persist action for `User` entity.

It will look like:

```
    ...
    @ManyToOne(optional=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID")
    public User getUser() {
      return user;
    }
    ...
```

Well, if there is not other error, it could work. I'm little confused with `optional=true`, cuz it can provide id with `deviceId,null` but that could be OK also.

Comment: yeah the optional thing was a cut and paste error thanks for the advice